# Text input with background color

Tags: php

I have the following code to load the colour  of an input field based on the value of `gap`

```
echo "<td class='gap'>";
echo "<input name = gap-".$compi['Competence_ID']." type='text' readonly style='width:20px;' value='";
if(isset($compi['gap']) && $compi['gap']!=0){
    echo $compi['gap'];
}
$color='';
if($compi['gap']>=0){
    $color='#3CB371';$text="gap bigger than 0";
}
if($compi['gap']<0){
    $color='#FFFFFF';$text="gap is not";
}
echo "' style='background-color:".$color.";'>";
echo $text."</td>";
```

The code prints correctly the `$text` but the colour of the input does not change..

Comment: Please post the rendered html.  At a quick glance it looks like you are creating two style attributes and that could be the source of your problem.

Comment: Have you checked the outputted HTML to see if the style is being updated, but not displaying?

Comment: This is not an PHP question, it's CSS or HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have two `style` attributes for your `<input>` tag - add both CSS rules in one attribute and you should be fine.

Comment: Yes; I realized that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo '<td class="gap">';
echo '<input name = "gap-'.$compi['Competence_ID'].'" type="text" readonly value="';
if(isset($compi['gap']) && $compi['gap']!=0){
    echo $compi['gap'];
}
$color='';
if($compi['gap']>=0){
    $color='#3CB371';$text="gap bigger than 0";
}
if($compi['gap']<0){
    $color='#FFFFFF';$text="gap is not";
}
echo '" style="width:20px;background-color:'.$color.';">';
echo $text."</td>";
```

Remember that HTML attributes should be between double quotes AND these quotes should not be fault. Theres was an fault quote on `name` attribute. And there must be no duplicate attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS proberty "color" is for the text color, "background-color" is what you're searching for :)

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp

Comment: I unfortunately updated the code before you posted this answer. The background-color attribute did not change anything..

Comment: However, you code is going to be `style='width:20px;' value='style='background-color:#FFFFF'`, which isn't right anyway

Comment: So, there is the other problem which should be solved. Thnx @RoyalBg